# error booting the custom compiled kernel 2.6.37 on ubuntu 10.04 : gave up waiting on root device

Tags: linux, kernel, compiling

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Kernel can't find /dev/sda file during boot](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/8405/kernel-cant-find-dev-sda-file-during-boot)

Hi,
    I know this is very common problem and there are many threads discussing it. However after trying many solutions my problem still persists :(

I have installed ubuntu Lucid which works fine.Then I  downloaded and compiled kernel 2.6.37 from git tree and compiled it using normal compilation process.I created initrd image and called

> update-grub

It detects my initrd image. However,I get following error while booting:

> Gave up waiting for root device.
>   Common problems:
>   -Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline)
>   -Check rootdelay= (did the system wait long enough?)
>   -Check root= (did the system wait for the right device?)
>   -Missing modules (cat /proc/modules; ls /dev)
>   ALERT! root=UUID=/... does not exist

And then control falls onto  **initramfs** prompt. 
I tried following solutions:

- Write GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true in /etc/default/grub
- compile kernel using CONFIG_DEVTMPFS=y

Still I am unable to boot from the boot the compiled kernel.
Could someone please suggest me some solution . Thank you :)